# most efficient way to search in sorted binary tree

Tags: c#, search, binary-tree

Suppose I have a binary tree, I am give the head of the tree (left values
are smaller than the values on the right), inside the tree there are ip address, e.g:

```
       2.1.1.7
      /       \
     /         \
1.1.10.17      3.4.4.5
```

I need to write a function that searches for this specific address.

For now what I did it's Inorder traversal like:

```
private HashSet<string> adr = new HashSet<string>();    
void Inorder(Node root){
  if(root.Left != null)
    Inorder(root.Left);
    adr.Add(root.Data);// <----root.Data it's an ip address (string)
  if(root.Right != null)
    Inorder(root.Right);
 }
```

Constractor:

```
private Node root;// <--- points to the root of the addresses tree

public MyClass{
  Inorder(root);
}
```

Finction:

```
bool FindAddress(string address){
 return adr.Contains(address);
}
```

But in my method I didn't used the fact that the tree is sorted, do you have an idea for better performance idea? with loop/recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your `FindAddress` function as follows to take advantage of the fact the data is sorted:

```
var node = FindAddress(IPAddress.Parse(searchAddress), assembledTree, new IPAddressCompare());

static Node FindAddress(IPAddress address, Node root, IComparer<IPAddress> addressCompare)
{        
    if (root == null) return null;
    var comp = addressCompare.Compare(IPAddress.Parse(root.Data), address);
    if (comp == 0) return root;
    if (comp < 0) return FindAddress(address, root.Left, addressCompare);
    if (comp > 0) return FindAddress(address, root.Right, addressCompare);
    return null;
}
```

Utilising a custom comparer to compare two different IP addresses by changing their representation to an Int32, considering the bytes at the start of the address most significant.

```
public class IPAddressCompare : IComparer<IPAddress>
{
    public int Compare(IPAddress x, IPAddress y)
    {
        var intA = BitConverter.ToUInt32(x.GetAddressBytes().Reverse().ToArray(), 0);
        var intB = BitConverter.ToUInt32(y.GetAddressBytes().Reverse().ToArray(), 0);
        return intB.CompareTo(intA);
    }
}
```

Full example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/viRy5b

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the simple list and use the Binary search with a comparer. Avoids the hastle of creating your own tree and performance is best.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;



class app
{    
    static void Main()
    {
        List<IPAddress> sortedIPs = new List<IPAddress>();

        AddToList(sortedIPs, new byte[4] { 6, 10, 54, 100 });
        AddToList(sortedIPs, new byte[4] { 143, 0, 254, 10 });
        AddToList(sortedIPs, new byte[4] { 48, 0, 0, 1 });
        AddToList(sortedIPs, new byte[4] { 0, 0, 82, 19 });
        AddToList(sortedIPs, new byte[4] { 13, 0, 254, 1 });
        AddToList(sortedIPs, new byte[4] { 63, 93, 4, 111 });
        AddToList(sortedIPs, new byte[4] { 98, 3, 74, 1 });
        AddToList(sortedIPs, new byte[4] { 98, 4, 74, 1 });
        AddToList(sortedIPs, new byte[4] { 98, 3, 14, 1 });
        AddToList(sortedIPs, new byte[4] { 98, 3, 14, 2 });
        AddToList(sortedIPs, new byte[4] { 7, 175, 25, 65 });
        AddToList(sortedIPs, new byte[4] { 46, 86, 21, 91 });

        IPAddress findAddress = new IPAddress(new byte[4] { 48, 0, 0, 1 });

        int index = sortedIPs.BinarySearch(findAddress, new IPAddressComparer());

    }

    private static void AddToList(List<IPAddress> list, byte[] address)
    {
        IPAddress a1 = new IPAddress(address);
        IPAddressComparer ipc = new IPAddressComparer();
        int index = list.BinarySearch(a1, ipc);
        if (index >= 0) throw new Exception("IP address already exists in list");
        list.Insert(~index, a1);
    }

    public class IPAddressComparer : IComparer<IPAddress>
    {
        public int Compare(IPAddress x, IPAddress y)
        {
            byte[] xb = x.GetAddressBytes();
            byte[] yb = y.GetAddressBytes();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                int result = xb[i].CompareTo(yb[i]);
                if (result != 0) return result; 
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```